# Control bound to a function but the function cannot access factory of another module

Tags: angularjs

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/n4jxLd7n/)  where a control is bound to a functon that uses a factory from another module. this.xyzFactory is undefined. Can anyone help me ?

```
function getName1() {
    return this.xyzFactory.getName(); //undefined
}
```

Comment: `angular.js` lib is not supporting to ur DOM in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but in your code angular.js is not supporting to your html, so if you want to use online lib then try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js" >
</script>
<script>
    angular.module('MyApp', [])
            .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope,xyzFactory) {

        $scope.appName = xyzFactory.getName("bob");
})
.factory('xyzFactory', function() {
       return {
          getName: function (name) {
             return name;
          }
      }
  })
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div>
    Hello {{ appName }}<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```